# Arrays as Queues in PHP

Tags: php, data-structures

I want to implement a queue in PHP, and looking at the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php)
, I found this example:

```
$queue = array("orange", "banana");
array_unshift($queue, "apple", "raspberry");
print_r($queue);
```

This creates the array:

```
array('apple', 'raspberry', 'orange', 'banana');
```

In this case 'banana' is at the beginning of the queue and it can be retrieved using `array_pop()`.

I guess that might be the traditional approach, but is there any good reason for not reversing the data in the array as follows?

```
$queue = array('apple', 'orange');
$queue[] = 'banana';//avoid function call
array_push($queue, 'strawberry', 'grape');//add multiple items
$next = array_shift($queue);
```

Maybe it's trivial, but in that way you could avoid a function call when adding a single element. Is there some other good reason for not doing it that way?

**EDIT:**

It appears that my question was a little hard to understand, so to make it easier to see that my method really does implement a queue according to the FIFO principle, I wrote this code to correspond with the example from the PHP manual, producing the exact same array (except in reverse order):

```
$queue = array('banana', 'orange');
$queue[] = 'rasberry';
$queue[] = 'apple';
```

This creates the array:

```
array('banana', 'orange', 'rasberry', 'apple');
```

It's the exact same data but in reverse order, so to retreive the next item you would do so with:

```
$next = array_shift($queue);//The value of $next is 'banana' as before.
```

As already pointed out by the answers, this runs up against how most people visualize a queue. It seems that readability is the major issue. However, I find it easier to code. To me, it actually seems more natural, because the square bracket notation `[]` is the doorway through which my array elements enter in numerous circumstances. Therefore, implementing either a stack or a queue really isn't a question about how I mentally visualize my data. It's a question of what function to use to access the first or last element that passed through the door. For a queue it's `array_shift()`, and for a stack it's `pop()`.

Comment: micro-optermisation is the path to madness. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater.html

Comment: Both are functionally equal. As long as you know which functions to use, they will both work.

Comment: I'm missing how the data is reversed.  Do you mean one is prepending, while the other is appending?  You would use each according to the business logic, not one in lieu of the other...

Comment: @landons - In the manual, the first item in is banana - at the end of the array. In my example, it's apple at the beginning of the array.

Comment: Still not sure I follow.  Example: `array('apple', 'raspberry', 'orange', 'banana');`.  Yours: `array('apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'strawberry', 'grape');`

Comment: I don't think that's correct.  Apple appears to be at the beginning of both queues.

Comment: @landons - Please read my comments to Don. I don't know how else to explain it. Both methods can produce the exact same FIFO results. It's just a matter of representing the data in reverse order. In the manual's example you would have to use pop() to pull from the end of the array rather than array_shift() which pulls from the beginning. I would therefore pull apple, whereas they would be pulling banana.

Comment: Ok, your question is finally making sense.  I don't think it matters, as long as you're consistent.  Use `array_push()` with `array_shift()` -OR- `array_unshift()` with `array_pop()` (to add/remove from queue, respectively).  In this sense, yes, I would prefer your method of appending, rather than prepending, to implement a queue.  Now, why are we wasting time with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it the first way (shortest code, easiest to follow) unless you have a **specific** and **valid** reason for using the second approach. While `$queue[] = 'banana'` *may* be faster (I believe it is but don't know for sure), the difference is so small that you shouldn't worry about it unless you're doing millions of operations or something where it would actually make a difference.

Comment: I have no problem with reading my code, and I don't have anyone coding with me, so I think I'll stick with it. It appears there is no significant difference except as you say, readability. And it really seems to confuse some people, even though it works just the same. All in all, it looks like you have the best answer. Thanks.

Comment: It confuses people because we're comparing apples and raspberries.

Comment: @PédeLeão yeah, it's all preference really. if you're working on a personal project or something then definitely do it however you'd like. in fact, i think you've got a point—`$queue[]` and `array_shift` are less characters (i.e. less typing) than `array_unshift` and `array_pop`. but personally, i wouldn't want to have to remind myself to think of the array in reverse in my head.

Comment: Since I haven't worked much with queues and stacks, I have a clean slate, so it doesn't confuse me at all. In fact, it's easy for me to think of the first element in an array as the first in a queue or as the bottom of the stack.

Comment: @PédeLeão ah, gotcha. all i meant was that it's weird for me as a programmer to conceptualize a stack as an array with elements in reverse order, where arr[0] is the "last" item in the array (i.e. first out of the queue). but of course it all depends on how you look at it.

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference before first approach and second - apart function calling.

`array_unshift()` will add your elements "at the top" (read them as in first position) of your array. `$queue[]` will ad element at the bottom.

Except this, both approach are equal valid

## Edit

"There any good reason for not reversing the data?"

Yes, there is: if you want to implement a "classic" queue (read it as FIFO) you have to use first approach; is faster, is more readable and will not introduce "semantical" errors. With second method, as you insert a single element on the bottom of the queue, you're not implementing a FIFO.

```
$queue = array("apple", "orange");
array_unshift($queue, "banana");
array_unshift($queue, 'strawberry', 'grape');

echo "First Approach<br/>";
print_r($queue);

$queue = array('apple', 'orange');
$queue[] = 'banana';//avoid function call
array_push($queue, 'strawberry', 'grape');//add multiple items
$next = array_shift($queue);

echo "Second Approach<br/>";
print_r($queue);
```

will produce a different output

```
First Approach
Array ( [0] => strawberry [1] => grape [2] => banana [3] => apple [4] => orange ) Second Approach
Array ( [0] => orange [1] => banana [2] => strawberry [3] => grape )
```

answer is here in front of you

Comment: Why would you use push and unshift in the first approach? Using push is like letting people cut in line. My example uses FIFO quite well. As you can see, orange is now at the front of the line where it should be. Apple was first, orange secong, etc.

Comment: @PédeLeão: because I want to "bring back" first case to second and don't know how to do. And no, orange should not be first element. Why should it be? If is a FIFO, "banana" (or event better "strawberry") should be first element

Comment: You're not grasping the idea of data in reverse order. Orange was in the queue before banana or strawberry were added. Grape was the very last one added. How could strawberry be the first in the queue when it was the second to last to get added?

Comment: Orange was int queue before, so it has to be shiffed "right" (so, near the "bottom" of the array). Strawberry should be first because if I insert array(strawberry, grape) I mean that grape is inserted before strawberry. If you would to intend to consider the opposite, grape should be first.

Comment: You're not getting it. The first line of code defines a queue with an opple and orange. That is first as in sequence or as in time. Apple and orange where in the queue before anything was added. They were therefore the first two. Apple was first in and first out. Get it?

Comment: @PédeLeão: yes, at creation time (and it isn't true through and through as orange is second element inserted, not first). BUT `$queue[] = 'banana';` this operation that in a queue has to result in banana insertion at top of queue. Iyour second example this result in "banana" insertion at the bottom: this isn't a queue. If you don't get it, maybe you asked for a thing that isn't so much clear in your mind ...

Comment: If you don't understand the sequence just look at the array keys. Orange has 0, banana 1, etc. Banana falls in line right after orange as it should.

Comment: @PédeLeão: is also [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_%28abstract_data_type%29) wrong?

Comment: I downvoted your answer not only because it's not helpful, but it's simply wrong in two respects: First, your code uses both unshift() and push(), inserting elements at both ends of the same queue, which demonstrates no understanding of FIFO. Second, even though you don't understand, others (landons, sgroves, Jonathan Kuhn) have already agreed that my method is functionally equivalent and implements FIFO correctly.

Comment: @PédeLeão: I use both only for emulate your example. I perfectly know how FIFO works.

Comment: to emulate, write it like this:
$queue = array('orange', 'apple');
array_unshift( $queue, 'banana');
array_unshift( $queue, 'grape', 'strawberry');

Comment: @PédeLeão: last example will produce different output respect your second approach of original question.

Comment: That's because I used array_shift() to get the apple. Add one more line to the code in my comment: $next = array_pop();, and you should also end up with an apple. Dump the array and you'll have the data in reverse order: grape, strawberry, banana, orange. Everything is reversed. You have to consistently reverse everything or it won't work.